# Excel generated using ExcelJS lib is not treating HH:MM column as hour

Tags: javascript, excel, datetime, exceljs

I'm applying the mask "HH:MM" on every cell of a specific column, but the Excel generated doesn't consider the cells as HH:MM unless I select it, so it doesn't sum the hours, it only count the cells, how can I fix it?

```js
worksheet1.getColumn(5).eachCell({ includeEmpty: false }, function(cell, rowNumber) {
    if(rowNumber > 1) {
        cell.style = {
            numRmt: "[h]:mm"
        };
    }
});
worksheet1.autoFilter = {
    from: { row: 1, column: 1 },
    to: { row: 1, column: 7 }
};
```

How it is treated on the Excel:

[image: How it is treated on the Excel]

How it is treated after I clicked on the cells:

[image: How it is treated after I clicked on the cells]

I tried to create a new Date object and set it's hours and minutes with what I wanted and feeding this object into the cell value instead. This made Excel correctly consider the value as a Date, but the auto sum got messed up.

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of code.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs#styles

It seems like the correct way to apply styles to a cell instead of column is by using the `numFmt` property directly instead of `style.numFmt`. Try the following and see whether it solves your issue:

```js
worksheet1
  .getColumn(5)
  .eachCell({ includeEmpty: false }, function (cell, rowNumber) {
    if (rowNumber > 1) {
      cell.numFmt = '[h]:mm';
    }
  });
```

In addition, based on the code, it seems like you are trying to override the internal `style` property, which can have unexpected side effects: https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/2ab468b8bae2c8d5844f922d61ac7d960fee26be/lib/doc/cell.js#L55-L57

Comment: It didn't work :( 
Excel keeps treating the column the same

Answer (score 0):

*edited*

In order for Excel to treat a date type cell as a time-only type cell you need to put in a **certain date** (also make sure you put in your timezones gmt offset)

For a **non-1904-based workbook** this would be `Sat Dec 30 1899`:

```js
const gmt = 1 // GMT+0100
yourRow.getCell(yourCell).value = new Date(1899, 11, 30, 8 + gmt, 52)
```

this will give you `08:52:00` in your spreadsheet cell, formated as time cell type

**beware**: when using a non-1904-based workbook there seems to be some rounding error so you might want to add at least one millisecond:

```js
const gmt = 1 // GMT+0100
let date = new Date(1899, 11, 30, 8 + gmt, 52);
date.setSeconds(0, 1); // zero seconds, one millisecond
yourRow.getCell(yourCell).value = date;
```

that doesn't fix it completely, it only gives you a correct formating for a single time cell - as soon as you start doing math with multiple of those the error will come into play again...

also in a non-1904-based workbook there can't be any negative times!

therefor I would suggest: **use a 1904-based workbook!**

For a **1904-based workbook** the date in question would be `Fri Jan 01 1904`:

```js
yourWorkbook.properties.date1904 = true;

const gmt = 1 // GMT+0100
yourRow.getCell(yourCell).value = new Date(1904, 0, 1, 8 + gmt, 52)
```

Now, that should do the trick and give you a "correct" `08:52:00` time cell type value